# MYSQL Query in Database View

Tags: mysql, database, view

```
SELECT `aversio`.`module`.`module` AS `module`

FROM   
       `projectmodule`
  JOIN `module`  ON `aversio`.`projectmodule`.`moduleID` = `aversio`.`module`.`moduleID`

  JOIN `project` ON `aversio`.`project`.`projectID` = `aversio`.`projectmodule`.`projectID`


WHERE `aversio`.`module`.`actief` = _utf8'1'
  AND `aversio`.`projectmodule`.`verwijderd` = _utf8'0'
  AND `aversio`.`projectmodule`.`verwijderd` = _utf8'0'
```

> MYSQL Error :   There is no 'aversio'@'%' registered

What this error mean

Comment: Have you tried removing all `()`? they are unnecessary.

Comment: Also those backticks are probably unnecessary, unless it is made by a code generator.

Comment: I think that this: `aversio.projectmodule.verwijderd` contains one element too much. MySQL doesn't support this IIRC. Try removing the `aversio` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually looks like a permissions issue, like you are trying to connect as `aversio` to a MySQL server instance which is not configured to allow that user from any (%) domain.

The syntax 'aversio'@'%' looks like the format 'username'@'host', and mysql uses % as the catch-all (any) host wildcard.

Make sure that you create the MySQL user named aversio, and give them the correct permissions on your DB.

EDIT:

IIRC, a user of that name may exist, but with a different domain (i.e. the users table is keyed on the combo of user and host. I've seen this kind of thing happen when I move code from a dev server to a staging server and try to connect fro mthe new host, having forgotten to modify the permissions in MySQL.

Comment: you are the man ctrahey. i want you to save in my $kype=uologic